# Account kit country code background color

Tags: android, android-theme, account-kit

[image]I used account kit by facebook and I am unable to find the background color for country code picker. It shows black color don't know. 
**Sharing my app theme.**

```
<style name="AppLoginTheme" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
        <item name="com_accountkit_primary_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_primary_text_color">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_secondary_color">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_secondary_text_color">@color/colorTextSecondary</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_status_bar_color">@color/colorPrimaryDarkL</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_background_color">@color/colorOverlay</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_input_background_color">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_input_border_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_button_disabled_background_color">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_button_disabled_border_color">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_button_background_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_button_text_color">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_icon_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_background">@drawable/ak_background</item>
        <item name="com_accountkit_toolbar_elevation">8dp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background color of country code selector will be same as the background color of the whole screen.
So to make it look better you'll have to change the ***com_accountkit_input_accent_color*** to white or some other color.

Comment: Okay... just checked. But I am using background image so I need to set background color transparent. and com_accountkit_input_accent_color  didn't work.